# Ejecutar .exe desde el servidor apache

Tags: php, c#, shell, exe

Buen día,

Tengo una aplicación la cual al clickear un botón me debe abrir el scanner de mi pc, para iniciar una digitalización, pero tengo varios problemas:

1. PHP no permite conectarse desde el servidor hasta el equipo local (o si alguien conoce alguna manera se lo agradecería y me compartiera la información).
2. Hice un programa en consola con c# que me inicialice el scanner, ese .exe lo subí al servidor apache.. pero al intentar iniciar me dice:

`Array
(
    [0] => exec_scanner.exe: exec_scanner.exe: cannot execute binary file
)`

Si alguien sabe como colaborar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Con respecto al .exe prueba : exec("aplicacion.exe");

Comment: Si te refieres a una aplicacion web, por motivos de seguridad me temo que es imposible lo que quieres hacer,a no ser quizá utilizando ActiveX o similares..

Comment: Lo que comentan los dos ya lo he realizado.

Aunque activex solo funciona para IE pero no es viable para mi, igual, muchas gracias!

Comment: Eventualmente se podría hacer con CGI, ¿has tratado algo por el estilo?

Comment: hola buenos dias andres galeano como haces la llamada desde php para que llame al .exe

Comment: @PETERBARRANCO es mediante un protocolo desde windows
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45923/27358 verifica ese link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día chicos.

agradezco mucha su ayuda pero ninguna de las sugerencias pude aplicarla.

Lo hice de la siguiente forma: URL protocol, y quedo algo parecido a Skype para realizar llamadas. Skype:nameskype?call pero en este caso sería nombreProyecto: Al poner esto desde la aplicación web funciona, aunque debe tener un programa que instale esos protocolos en el equipo de la persona que va a usar x funcion del sistema que requiere conectarse al equipo, en mi caso lo hice mediante c# creando los regedit automaticamente, dejo link de ayuda PD todo se hace desde el HKEY_CLASSS_ROOT:

[Link Url Protocol -> pasos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas.

Si lo que tienes es una aplicación web en un hosting en la nube, no es posible acceder a tú escaner ya que éste no se encuentra alojado en el mismo servidor.

De igual manera al ejecutar el .exe éste no hallará el dispositivo en cuestión.

Seria más factible que tús usuarios realicen un updload de los archivos que quieres almacenar.

Comment: Si, es real lo que dices.

Ya los usuarios pueden adjuntar el archivo, el dilema esta en el scanner, muchas gracias de igual manera.

Comment: Cambia el proceso. Escanear en local y luego crear una opción para subir los archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Una aplicación web en un servidor fuera de la red local por seguridad no tiene acceso a los periféricos de los equipos clientes sino únicamente al contexto web en el que son ejecutados, para tu caso sugiero limitarse al campo de upload de imágenes.